# Coverting List of Dictionary to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, casting, datatable

Currently we are doing this by looping through each value of list and dictionary:

```
private DataTable ChangeToDictionary(List<Dictionary<string,int>> list)
       {
           DataTable datatTableReturn = new DataTable();

           if (list.Count() > 0)
           {
               Dictionary<string, int> haeders = list.ElementAt(0);
               foreach (var colHead in haeders)
               {
                   datatTableReturn.Columns.Add(colHead.Key);
               }
           }

           foreach (var row in list)
           {
               DataRow dataRow = datatTableReturn.NewRow();
               foreach (var col in row)
               {

                   dataRow[col.Key] = col.Value;
               }
               datatTableReturn.Rows.Add(dataRow);
           }
           return datatTableReturn;

       }
```

But is there a better way? Looping through so many times doesn't feel good

Comment: Like what? Any other approach would eventually need to go over all your data c.q. loop over the records. I don't see the real problem that you are having. You dislike the above code?

Comment: This works, but as said is there a better ,robust way

Comment: Why convert to a DataTable in the first place?

Comment: @Jodrell, Because DataTable can is not there in Seilverlight and sometimes not serializable while returning from service

Comment: but, if the thing that needs the `DataTable` worked with an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` for instance ...

Comment: What do you want to achieve? More speed? Reusability of code? Code elegance? For starters, don't use `Count()` extension method on `List<T>`. Use `Count` property instead.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević, For now Speed and Elegance is what I'll say

Answer (score 21):

The answers above don't address the issue of the dictionary having more than 1 row. This solution addresses the issue.

```
static DataTable ToDataTable(List<Dictionary<string, int>> list)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    if (list.Count == 0)
        return result;

    var columnNames = list.SelectMany(dict=>dict.Keys).Distinct();
    result.Columns.AddRange(columnNames.Select(c=>new DataColumn(c)).ToArray());
    foreach (Dictionary<string,int> item in list)
    {
        var row = result.NewRow();
        foreach (var key in item.Keys)
        {
            row[key] = item[key];
        }

        result.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, int>> it = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.Add("a", 1);
    dict.Add("b", 2);
    dict.Add("c", 3);
    it.Add(dict);
    dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.Add("bob", 34);
    dict.Add("tom", 37);
    it.Add(dict);
    dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dict.Add("Yip Yip", 8);
    dict.Add("Yap Yap", 9);
    it.Add(dict);

    DataTable table = ToDictionary(it);
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        Console.Write("{0}\t", col.ColumnName);
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            Console.Write("{0}\t", row[column].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

And the output looks like...

```
a       b       c       bob     tom     Yip Yip Yap Yap
1       2       3
                        34      37
                                        8       9
```

Comment: your output doesn't match your input.

Comment: (facepalm) oops. you are right. I accidentally used the wrong iterator. Edited with correction.

Comment: This was a time-saver. Kudos!

Comment: to populate the dataTable's Columns you cloud also use: foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> entry in myDictonary)
            {
                myTable.Columns.Add(entry.Key);
            }

Answer (score 7):

Speed, elegance and reusability don't go together. You always choose more important one, and try to balance other two.

Faster the code, uglier it is.
Prettier it is, less reusable it is.

Here's an example of "elegant" solution, but that goes with it not being very readable.

```
private static DataTable ToDictionary(List<Dictionary<string, int>> list)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    if (list.Count == 0)
        return result;

    result.Columns.AddRange(
        list.First().Select(r => new DataColumn(r.Key)).ToArray()
    );

    list.ForEach(r => result.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: you iterate the first row twice.

Comment: There is no fixed relationship between performance and readability. Fast code can be readable code. Ugliness is purely subjective.

Comment: Maybe I should have said "simpler". You can't say that implementation of quick sort is simpler than implementation of bubble sort.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> ListDic;

var stringListDic = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListDic);

var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(stringListDic);
```

Comment: The best solution, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the code below?

Good, because it iterates each row exactly once. It should be pretty quick, I've included obvious exceptions to make the code safer.

```
private static DataTable DictionariesToDataTable<T>(
        IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, T>> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = new DataTable();
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (e.Current.Keys.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        var length = e.Current.Keys.Length;

        result.Columns.AddRange(
            e.Current.Keys.Select(k => new DataColumn(k, typeof(T))).ToArray());

        do
        {
            if (e.Current.Values.Length != length)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            result.Rows.Add(e.Current.Values);
        }
        while (e.MoveNext());

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not disposing the enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDictionaries<T>(List<Dictionary<string, T>> list)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        if (list == null || !list.Any()) return dataTable;

        foreach (var column in list.First().Select(c => new DataColumn(c.Key, typeof(T))))
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        foreach (var row in list.Select(
            r =>
                {
                    var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    r.ToList().ForEach(c => dataRow.SetField(c.Key, c.Value));
                    return dataRow;
                }))
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try my solution, seems very clean to me:

```
private DataTable DictonarysToDataTable(List<Dictionary<string, int>> list) 
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (Dictionary<string,string> dict in list)        //for every dictonary in the list ..
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string,int> entry in dict) //for every entry in every dict
            {
                if (!myTable.Columns.Contains(entry.Key.ToString()))//if it doesn't exist yet
                {
                    myTable.Columns.Add(entry.Key);                 //add all it's keys as columns to the table
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dict.Values.ToArray());              //add the the Values of every dict in the list as a new row
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Edit:
Oh Snap, this works only for one Dictionary .. i didn't think it through.
But maybie you can modify it to work for a List of Dictionarys ..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try please

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> row in DeviceTypeReport)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in row)
            {
                if (!table.Columns.Contains(entry.Key.ToString()))
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(entry.Key);
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row.Values.ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataTable toDataTable(List<RetirementDiskModelDto> retirementDiskModelDtos)
        {
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            foreach (var col in retirementDiskModelDtos.FirstOrDefault().Items)
                result.Columns.Add(col.Key);

            foreach (var row in retirementDiskModelDtos)
            {
                DataRow newrow = result.NewRow();
                foreach (var col in retirementDiskModelDtos.FirstOrDefault().Items)
                    newrow[col.Key] = col.Value;
                result.Rows.Add(newrow);
            }
            return result;
        }
```